# GLFW No monitors found in LWJGL 3 application

Tags: java, lwjgl, glfw

So this problem came about a day ago in a program I'd been working on for quite a while now. All of the sudden GLFW failed to initialize every single time I launched it. After further investigation (Adding an error callback) I found that GLFW can't find any monitors and thus fails at any further calls. The code was never changed, it just suddenly decided to not work. I've updated my drivers and everything, but nothing is working. I even launched an old C++ program using GLFW and it worked fine, just LWJGL fails. Not even the [Hello, World!](http://www.lwjgl.org/guide) app on LWJGL's website works. I'm not uploading code since you can refer to the LWJGL [Hello, World!](http://www.lwjgl.org/guide) app.

Edit: I downloaded and earlier version of LWJGL and it worked, but I would like to use the newest version.

Comment: Which platform are you using? Does glfwGetMonitors also return NULL? [The documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__monitor.html#ga721867d84c6d18d6790d64d2847ca0b1) says NULL is returned when an error occurs - was there one?

Comment: Using LWJGL 3 Release (3.0.0a) And on startup (Before calling glfwInit()) The error callback (First GLFW function called) yells at me saying "no monitors found"

Comment: Might be related to GLFW issues [#441](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/441) and [#556](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/556). Which operating system are you using? I myself have never experienced this issue even with the latest versions - could you try the latest nightly build (#3.0.0b build 20)? See also [a related thread on the forums](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5888.0).

Comment: Windows 10 with LWJGL 3.0.0a Release